# Selecting the best solution to store data for an Android Password Safe app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, serialization, encryption

For those which are not familiar with password safe app types its simply an app that stores passwords or other sensitive data.

I haven't been ancrypting in java yet. I came up with 2 solutions after a research.

1) Using an SQLite database and somehow encrypt that (I've read that might be problematic, cause troubles with acquiring data and might require some custom libs)

2) Using serialized objects stored into encrypted files (sounds reasonable, however acquiring data won't be that comfy as from a database)

**What is very important:** I must have easy way for backing up data. On SD card for example. It would be easy if it comes to database. Dont know about serialized encrypted objects though...

Which one you think is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely option 1.

You might want to consider [this project](http://code.google.com/p/android-passwordsafe/) (source available), it does exactly what you want using [AES Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

Comment: looks very useful. I'm defineatly gonna look into this.

Answer (score 0):

First solution is better anyway. There must be no problems if you do it right and spent some time for researching and testing!

Can`t give you direct link, but this method was used in many of my projects.